# How to install linux on a external hdd connected to iMac

Tags: install, external-disk, dual-boot

How to install linux on an external HDD which is a 5TB Seagate OneTouch HDD and is connected with iMac through a USB 3 cable?

I am new to Linux, at the moment I consider to try Linux Mint. And I want to make two partitions to this HDD. One for linux system and applications, the other one for shared data from both Linux and Mac. Please help with steps as detailed as possible. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Since you want precise instructions, you probably should include a better description of your Mac. Include details such as year, screen size, memory installed, version of macOS (OS X) installed, model identifier, etc. Can the entire external drive be erased or will the installation share space with existing partitions (volumes)?

Answer (score 1):

The short and simple answer (assuming your particular iMac can run your chosen Linux distro) is to boot the Linux installer and let it it install/copy the relevant files to your connected drive. To boot from other partitions than the boot volume on your Mac, you’ll have to hold the <kbd>Option</kbd>key during boot up and select the volume to boot from.

However, I don’t recommend you do this since you are so new to Linux/Unix environments.

Instead, use a VM like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (v7 supports Apple Silicon, now) and create a machine there.  You can run it in seamless mode which will give you a full desktop experience without having to mess with dual booting your Mac.  If you make a mistake, only the VM is affected, not your whole system. You can create a shared folder anywhere on your system (internal, external, and even networked drives) and share it between the host and the VM quite easily.

Comment: Thank you Allan, I tried VirtualBox a couple of months ago, but I don't why, it was too slow on a 2017 iMac (3,4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 Radeon Pro 570 4 GB 8 GB 2400 MHz DDR4 Retina 5K 27-inch). Maybe you have better experience on more recent Macs. ❤️

Comment: You need much more RAM.  i still have a 2012 iMac with 32GB RAM that runs my virtual lab with 6 simultaneous VMs.  CPU isn’t thr issue…making sure they have resources is.

Comment: Thank yu Allan. I will check the posibility to upgrade my ram from 8 GB to at least 16 GB. ❤️